# Noob stuck Tensor flow adjusting the array shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

first thank you for any help that you can give. I am absolutely lost on the shape in tensensorflow. I have searched google, StackOverflow, discord, and youtube. I want to run a RNN on a CSV file.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras as keras

data = pd.read_csv("Big Data Chart Final no symbol.csv")
data.shape 
(2941, 120)
```

## I believe this is a 2d dimension array? My batch size is 120?

```
inputs=tf.placeholder('float',[None,2],name="input")
targets = tf.placeholder('float',name='Target')
```

#So I have 120 input neurons? Since I have 120 columns?

## then my input data is 120? and I have 2941 sets of inputs,correct? so my batch shape should be 2941,120?

I am getting lost even trying to explain it. AM I on the right track? I know there is a lot of info out there and I did read the documentation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

None is your Batchsize.  Your array you want to feed in begins afterwards. For example [None,255,255] will be a 255 by 255 picture with variable batchsize.